# How to call a module from a previous parent directory?

Tags: python-3.x, pythonanywhere

I am running a Flask application at PythonAnywhere. I'm using Python 3.8. The folder structure looks like this:

```
project/
    app.py
    alpha/
        beta/
            gamma/
            other.py
```

All of the folders have a blank `__init__.py`. From inside `other.py`, I want to do an import like:

```
from project.app import function
```

What is the cleanest way to make this happen?

I've seen suggestions to use `import importlib.util` in other answers. Will that work in PythonAnywhere? Instead of doing that in `other.py` is there a way to do this once and it work for the whole project? (so that things like `from project.alpha.beta import function` would work as well)

Answer (score 1):

I have a partial answer. Partial because I'm not sure it is the best answer. In the PythonAnywhere web configuration the working directory is listed as `/home/username/mysite/project`. As per the example above, project had a module I was trying to reference. So at the top of app.py (in the project folder), I added this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/username/mysite")
```

Basically I added the directory above the module directory to the import path. That got me through the error, but it doesn't seem like the best solution.

I do want to give a shoutout to this [PythonAnywhere help page](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError) because it has some good module debugging tips.